# FCM unreliable messaging with some messaging delays

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Problem is that when I'm sending a message from the Server to a specific client with the InstanceID which I get from Firebase, I don't always get a message.
Most of the time I don't even get a message and sometimes I get after 5-10 minutes a Message to the android device.

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{

public static final String SERVICE_RESULT = "at.ideafactory.spotted.Firebase.REQUEST_PROCESSED";
public static final String SERVICE_MESSAGE = "at.ideafactory.spotted.Firebase.REQUEST_MSG";

private LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
    notifyMainActivity(remoteMessage.getData().get("obj_location"));
}


public void notifyMainActivity(String data){
    if(data != null && data.length() != 0 && !data.equals("")){
        Intent intent = new Intent(SERVICE_RESULT);
        intent.putExtra(SERVICE_MESSAGE, data);
        broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}

}
```

Could anyone help me with my problem?
Do you know if it is possible on the device to check if notifications are available?

Kind Regards

Comment: You should also add in the title "and some Message delays".

Comment: Suggested title: FCM unreliable messaging with some delays.

Comment: This is most likely caused by the [unrealistic heartbeat intervals in GCM/FCM](https://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/). Consider [Pushy](https://pushy.me), a reliable push notification service that greatly improves notification speed & reliability on Android. Full disclosure - I work at Pushy.

Answer (score 1):

Could you test with the code provided by the Firebase [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L41-L69) and see if you receive the notification when you send the message? 
When I was testing FCM with this code, I was receiving the notification instantly. The problem could be in your server side or other part of your app.

```
/**
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
        // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now I noticed that there is a 'priority' Property in the JSON Object which I send from my app server to the FCM service.

Default: "priority":"normal"

I've set the "priority" to "high", now I'm able to receive the messages sent by my server in real time on the devices.

Comment: after update google play service. fcm is unrealible. even already set priority high and delay 0